# Can I Install SQL server 2000 Evaluation copy on Windows 7?

Tags: installshield-2010

When install SQL Server 2000 (Evaluation copy) on Windows 7 32 bit Home Premium desktop computer,

system gives the following error and Installation not successful:

> InstallShield Engine has stopped
>   working A problem caused the program
>   to stop working correctly. Windows
>   will close the program and notify you
>   if a solution is available.

Comment: Why is this tagged InstallShield-2010?  Eitherway it's a crazy thing to even want to do.  Even if you could get it installed you would be vunerable to network attacks with no support from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Sql server 2000 is not supported on Windows 7. You might be able to get it installed but you would have problems.

According to this blog posting you even need SP3 of Sql Server 2005 for it to work on Win7.

http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2009/10/23/sql-server-on-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx